# How to define an offset for a PatternColor fill in iText?

Tags: java, itext

I am trying to add tiled diagonal watermarks to the pdf, but it seems that pattern fills in iText are always tiled from the bottom left of the page, meaning that the tiles at the top and right side of the page can be cut abruptly. **Is there an option to tile from the top left or with an offset instead?**

Here is a sample of the code:

```
List<String> watermarkLines = getWatermarkLines();
Rectangle watermarkRect = getWatermarkRect();

PdfContentByte over = stamper.getOverContent(1);
PdfPatternPainter painter = over.createPattern(watermarkRect.getWidth(), watermarkRect.getHeight();
for (int x = 0; x < watermarkLines.size(); x++) {
  AffineTransform trans = getWatermarkTransform(watermarkLines, x);
  ColumnText.showTextAligned(painter, 0, watermarkLines.get(x), (float) trans.getTranslateX(), (float) trans.getTranslateY(), 45f);
}

over.setColorFill(new PatternColor(painter));
over.rectangle(0, 0, pageSize.getWidth(), pageSize.getHeight());
over.fill();
```

I tried changing the x and y of the `rectangle` function to negative or positive values, but it seems that the watermark is still stamped in the pattern as if it was tiled from the bottom left, cutting it in the same place as before.

Comment: Which iText version do you use? The versions I have around here require a `Phrase` instead of your `String` in `ColumnText.showTextAligned`.

Comment: Did my answer help you? Or are there still issues? In the former case please accept the answer (click the tick at its upper left), and in the latter case please tell us about the remaining issues in comments or (if much data or formatted data is involved) in edits to your question.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply: yes, the third parameter should have been a `Phrase` and not a `String`. And your answer worked like a charm. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*First of, I cannot fathom which iText version you are using,*

```
List<String> watermarkLines = getWatermarkLines();
...
ColumnText.showTextAligned(painter, 0, watermarkLines.get(x), (float) trans.getTranslateX(), (float) trans.getTranslateY(), 45f);
```

*implies that the third parameter of the `ColumnText.showTextAligned` method you use is typed as `String` or `Object`. The iText 5 version I have at hand, though, requires a `Phrase` there. Below I'll show how to apply an offset with the current iText 5.5.13. You'll have to check whether it also works for your version.*

Yes, you can apply an offset... in the pattern definition!

If instead of

```
PdfPatternPainter painter = over.createPattern(watermarkRect.getWidth(), watermarkRect.getHeight());
```

you create the pattern like this

```
PdfPatternPainter painter = over.createPattern(2 * watermarkRect.getWidth(), 2 * watermarkRect.getHeight(),
                                               watermarkRect.getWidth(), watermarkRect.getHeight());
```

you have the same step size of pattern application (`watermarkRect.getWidth(), watermarkRect.getHeight()`) but a canvas twice that width and twice that height to position you text on. By positioning the text with an offset, you effectively move the whole pattern by that offset.

E.g. if you calculate the offsets as

```
Rectangle pageSize = pdfReader.getCropBox(1);
float xOff = pageSize.getLeft();
float yOff = pageSize.getBottom() + ((int)pageSize.getHeight()) % ((int)watermarkRect.getHeight());
```

and draw the text using

```
ColumnText.showTextAligned(painter, 0, new Phrase(watermarkLines.get(x)), (float) trans.getTranslateX() + xOff, (float) trans.getTranslateY() + yOff, 45f);
```

the pattern should fill the page as if starting at the top left corner of the visible page.

You haven't supplied `getWatermarkLines`, `getWatermarkRect`, and `getWatermarkTransform`. If I use

```
static AffineTransform getWatermarkTransform(List<String> watermarkLines, int x) {
    return AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(6 + 15*x, 6);
}

static Rectangle getWatermarkRect() {
    return new Rectangle(65, 50);
}

static List<String> getWatermarkLines() {
    return Arrays.asList("Test line 1", "Test line 2");
}
```

your original code for me creates a top left corner like this

[image: screen shot original]

and the code with the above offset creates one like this

[image: screen shot with offset]

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for! The `xstep`  and `ystep` parameters for creating a pattern did the trick. Thanks!